# Necessary amount of context in edit summary

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, edit-summary

I am wondering how much of a post a reviewer actually sees when having to decide whether or not to accept an edit.

In the [concrete case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10910278) the OP posted two versions of an algorithm which he claimed to both compute the same result. However, this wasn't true and I decided to amend his second snippet to eventually make it produce the same output as the first one.

Disregarding the advices from this [meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/5717099), my edit summary was (admittedly) not overwhelmingly informative (*"corrected last example"*). Still, from the original text of the edited content it was clear (to me, at least) that both of those snippets should behave equally.

**Thus, my question:** Do I have to point out this fact again explicitly in my edit summary, since the reviewers cannot see the entire post in their view? Or am I simply expecting too much from an average reviewer to read and understand two simple C-style loops? - After all, the OP also was in need for some [persuasion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817909/5717099) before he ultimately made the edit himself.

Comment: I think that reviewers would rather  error on the side of caution and reject. Those reviewers got to see 1/7 th of what you got to see.

Comment: @Drew But there is no way for me to be notified of this (other than explicitly looking up the respective edit proposal and its status), right? - Because after all it boils down to having a correct or a wrong code sample up on SO. And this fact is naturally unrelated to the opinions of the reviewers.

Comment: The first half of what you just said seems to be talking about you receiving notification of the status of the pending edit. For that back then I would click on edit(n) and see where that status is at at the moment. If there are other notification possibilities, I don't know. If you are suggesting that after 1 reject that you tweak your edit, then I don't see that as possible.

Comment: For the last half of what you said, the opinions of the reviewers do matter because they are concerned with, among other things, audits and their name attached to approving poor edits. Now back to the original question or discussion: pertaining to persuasion, you simply do not have the flexibility to persuade in this medium of little text boxes like  Edit Reason and the like to persuade to your satisfaction reviewers in fast-paced Suggested Edit reviews. So in my opinion, because I have been there on your side, it is important to set a low expectation, then be surprised with Accepts.